# loss of information while binarizing an image: Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was trying to binarize some images. In some images I get the pattern as it is but in some images I lose some of the pattern. I am using greythresh for binarizing. Is there any other method to improve the output.

```
I = imread('image.jpg');

I = rgb2gray(I);
I = uint8(255*mat2gray(I));
figure,imshow(I);


I=imresize(I,[128 128]);
figure,imshow(I);

I = medfilt2(I,[5 5]);
I1 = medfilt2(I,[5 5]);


I = adapthisteq(I1,'clipLimit',0.4,'Distribution','rayleigh');
figure,imshow(I);


level = graythresh(I);
BW = im2bw(I, level);
figure,imshow(BW);
```

input

[image]

output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Getting a unique threshold for the whole image seems to be bad in your case. You should try to perform adaptive local thresholding to better adapt  to smooth image intensity variations.

You can find a matlab example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8647-local-adaptive-thresholding)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand how can we choose the window size and C based when we use different images